# Write data that can be read by ProtobufPigLoader from Elephant Bird

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, elephantbird

For a [project of mine](http://code.google.com/p/fs-c/), I want to analyse around 2 TB of [Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) objects. I want to consume these objects in a Pig Script via the ["elephant bird"](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird) library. However it is not totally clear to my how to write a file to HDFS so that it can be consumed by the ProtobufPigLoader class.

This is what I have:

**Pig script:**

```
  register ../fs-c/lib/*.jar // this includes the elephant bird library
  register ../fs-c/*.jar    
  raw_data = load 'hdfs://XXX/fsc-data2/XXX*' using com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.ProtobufPigLoader('de.pc2.dedup.fschunk.pig.PigProtocol.File');
```

**Import tool (parts of it):**

```
def getWriter(filenamePath: Path) : ProtobufBlockWriter[de.pc2.dedup.fschunk.pig.PigProtocol.File] = {
  val conf = new Configuration()
  val fs = FileSystem.get(filenamePath.toUri(), conf)
  val os = fs.create(filenamePath, true)
  val writer = new ProtobufBlockWriter[de.pc2.dedup.fschunk.pig.PigProtocol.File](os, classOf[de.pc2.dedup.fschunk.pig.PigProtocol.File])
  return writer
}
val writer = getWriter(new Path(filename))
val builder = de.pc2.dedup.fschunk.pig.PigProtocol.File.newBuilder()
writer.write(builder.build)
writer.finish()
writer.close()
```

The import tool runs fine. I had a few problems with the ProtobufPigLoader because I cannot use the hadoop-lzo compression library, and without a fix (see [here](https://github.com/dmeister/elephant-bird/commit/806808e5a70271fa23cfb0e79c5210618d4e7fa1)) ProtobufPigLoader isn't working. The problem where I have problems is that `DUMP raw_data;` returns `Unable to open iterator for alias raw_data` and `ILLUSTRATE raw_data;` returns `No (valid) input data found!`.

For me, it looks like the ProtobufBlockWriter data cannot be read by the ProtobufPigLoader. But what to use instead? *How to write data in a external tool to HDFS so that it can be processed by ProtobufPigLoader.*

*Alternative question:* What to use instead? How to write pretty large objects to Hadoop to consume it with Pig? The objects are not very complex, but contain a large list of sub-objects in a list (repeated field in Protobuf).

- I want to avoid any text format or JSON because they are simply to large for my data. I expect that it would bloat up the data by a factor of 2 or 3 (lots of integer, lots of byte strings that I would need to encode as Base64)..
- I want to avoid normalizing the data so that the id of the main object is attached to each of the subobjects (this is what is done [now](https://github.com/dmeister/fs-c/blob/master/contrib/fs-c-ir.pig)) because this also blows up the space consumption and makes joins necessary in the later processing.

Updates:

- I didn't use the generation of protobuf loader classes, but use the reflection type loader
- The protobuf classes are in a jar that is registered. `DESCRIBE` correctly shows the types.

Comment: Did you find an answer to these questions? I'm looking at doing the same thing. Thanks

Comment: No. I don't really need it anymore, but I started a bounty for it.

Comment: The uncomfortable thing of `elephant bird` is that it does not provide a simple way to remove the LZO dependency. However, we write our custom LoadFunc and StoreFunc to tackle our custom data based on `com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.util.ProtobufToPig` in `elephant bird`.

Comment: Not sure if it is sufficient, but perhaps this helps:   [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).